# Database connection through config.properties

Tags: java

I'm creating a program where (among other things) from the space for the user to change the url, name and password for the database connection.

In a class I get the values that are saved in a file and up to here everything ok. The problem arises when I'm in class concerning the connection of the batabase. The fault is not the OutProp method (which fetches the data in the properties file) because I tried it in another class and it works perfectly. So I guess there is a problem of writing code maybe in public static method Connection ConnectDb () as being static you have to behave differently, and since I have started recently to study Java I think I missed something.

PS. Writing `Connection conn = DriverManager. getConnection ("jdbc: mysql://localhost/databaseprogetto/root/root");` connects to the database.

Thank you for any suggestion or solution and I hope that I explained well.

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.sql.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Properties;

 public class JavaConnect {

 Connection conn = null;
 static String url_database;
 static String username;
 static String password;

 public void OutProp (){

 Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {   
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

            url_database = prop.getProperty("Url");
            username = prop.getProperty("Username");
            password = prop.getProperty("Password");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }


 public static Connection ConnectDb(){

    try{         
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url_database,username,password);

        return conn;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Please **make sure you have No space** on **either side** of the 2 operands in Property file.

**Eg:**

```
Property1=value1
Property2=value2
```

**2.** Try putting this `Property file` in the `bin` folder of your Project.